# Using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject in a Class Library Package targeting .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm having trouble resolving a missing reference when trying to use Json.NET's **JsonConvert.DeserializeObject** method in a Class Library Package targeting .NET Core.

To reproduce in VS2015:

1. Create a new Class Library Package using RC1.

[image: Class Library Package]

2. Install Newtonsoft.Json v8.0.2.
3. Target .NET Core. See the exact project.json file I'm using below.
4. In the default Class1 that's created, add this simple method:

   ```
   public void DoSomething()
   {
       var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("");
   }
   ```
5. You'll get the following error:

> The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0'

Any idea what reference I'm missing? I assume it's some kind of System.Serialization or System.IO package but I can't figure out which one.

project.json:

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"description": "ClassLibrary1 Class Library",
"authors": [ "DD" ],
"tags": [ "" ],
"projectUrl": "",
"licenseUrl": "",
"frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "netcore50": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0",
            "System.Collections": "4.0.0",
            "System.Linq": "4.0.0",
            "System.Runtime": "4.0.0",
            "System.Threading": "4.0.0"
        }
    }
},
"dependencies": {
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.2"
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this issue by adding a dependency of `Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility`. [[NuGet page]](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility/)

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ClassLibrary1 Class Library",
  "authors": [ "DD" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "netcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.0",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.0",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.0",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.2",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1-beta-23516"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use latest Newtonsoft.Json nuget package (at the moment it's 11.0.2) working fine without any problem with .NET Core 2.1.